# JPA save() can't get the last ID from an existing table

Tags: java, spring, jpa

When I save a new entity, it's Primary Key ID started saving from 1, as supposed to. But there were rows on the table before I implemented the JPA.

Entity.class:

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Table(schema = "db", name = "table")
    public class Entity {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
        private Long id;
    }
```

Example: Let's say there are 10 rows. I `.save()` a new entity and it saves with the `id = 5`, and of course I get an exception.

Do I need to keep saving until the generated ID gives a + 10 number. Is this normal? Can't the `@GeneratedValue` get the last id from the table and +1 itself?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting ?

Comment: IDENTITY means that the database is creating the ID with an auto increment like Mysql. What database are you using and how did you create the table?

Comment: Existing primary key, @Typhon. `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint` as it's trying to insert an ID of 5 when there are already 10 rows on the table. i.e it has a different auto increment than the table

Comment: I've tried auto, identity and table. All gave the same outcome, @SimonMartinelli it doesn't take the table's last row and increments it by 1. Posgresql by the way.

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: is your column auto increment? What is your db column definition?

Comment: `id serial primary key` was the query used for creating the id on the table, @muasif80

Comment: What is EntityBase? and why did you use it? remove this i don't think so its needed `updatable = false, ` and have you put implements serializable in EntityBase?

Comment: Sorry that was the same as the GeneratedValue and Id implementation. Not of use for the example @muasif80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the autogenerated ID. As I did have rows on the table before implementing the JPA, the auto increment started with 1.

Fixed by modifying the auto increment sequence:

`SELECT SETVAL('table_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM table));`

Comment: Good that you found the solution.